# How to convert a string to Date format

Tags: sql, datetime

I have the following sql statement line:

```
CAST(convert(varchar(10), CT.ATTR2752, 110) as datetime) 'New'
```

which displays:

```
2014-12-19 00:00:00.000
```

I am trying to convert it to `12-19-2014` and use it as DATE instead of a string.

How can I accomplish that?

I know I have to use CAST and CONVERT together but not sure how.

Comment: What does the CT.ATTR2752 look like to begin with? Can't you cast it to date directly?

Comment: Follow the article: http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: What is the data type of `CT.ATTR2752`, if its not datetime data type then what format it is stored in ?

Comment: The third parameter of `convert` is the style. I think it doesn't apply to varchar data type (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). And what exactly is the CT.ATTR2752 value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CAST(convert(varchar(10), CT.ATTR2752, 110) as date) 'New'
```

Comment: I am running sql 2012 and `date` is not a defined system type

Comment: @SiKni8 `Date` data type has been there since 2008.

Comment: I believe it is the limitation of the server we are using

Comment: @SiKni8 what version of ssms are you using?